# Drop foreign-key constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, constraints

How to drop a foreign key if I have not named it during creation

```
create table abc(
id number(10),
foreign key (id) references tab(roll)
);
```

even

```
 alter table abc drop foreign key mn_ibfk_1;
```

is not working for me. I am using Oracle 10g.

Comment: Add the error message please!

Comment: it says missing keyword!!

Comment: table _ibfk_1 is the default name given am I right here??

Comment: Add whole message please. Yes that is a default name.

Comment: SQL> alter table mn drop foreign key mn_ibfk_1;
    alter table mn drop foreign key mn_ibfk_1
                    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-00905: missing keyword

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you did not specify a constraint name, Oracle generated one for you (something like `SYS_034849548`).

You need to find the constraint name in order to be able to drop it:

```
select constraint_name
from user_constraints
where table_name = 'ABC'
  and constraint_type = 'R'
```

will display the constraint name. Then you can drop the constraint using:

```
alter table abc drop constraint <constraint_name>;
```

(replace `<constraint_name>` with the name you retrieved using the SQL statement)

Note that the syntax is `alter table ... drop constraint`. There is no `drop foreign key`.

Comment: BTW the name of the constraint is exactly the way you said I checked it by going in the oracle local server home page.

Comment: If it shows "*no rows select*" you either did not create a foreign key for that table or you supplied the wrong table name. Table names are stored in UPPPER case in the oracle system views. You need to supply your table name in upper case as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

alter table mn drop constraint mn_ibfk_1;

to find out for sure the name of the constraint try this query

```
SELECT a.table_name child_table,
        b.table_name parent_table,
        a.constraint_name child_constraint,
        b.constraint_name parent_constraint,
        c.column_name child_column,
        d.column_name parent_column
  FROM user_constraints a,
        user_constraints b,
        user_cons_columns c,
        user_cons_columns d
 WHERE        a.constraint_type = 'R'
        AND b.constraint_type = 'P'
        AND b.constraint_name = a.r_constraint_name
        AND A.table_name = c.table_name
        AND b.table_name = d.table_name
        AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
        AND b.constraint_name = d.constraint_name
        AND c.position = d.position
        AND a.table_name = 'mn' ;
```